# X and Y are distributed by the same distribution

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

I know that if $X_1 \tilde~ Poisson(\lambda_1)$ and $X_2 \tilde~ Poisson(\lambda_2)$ then $X+Y \tilde~ Poisson(\lambda_1 + \lambda_2)$

Is this true with any distribution? Or is it merely because here $E(X)=Var(X)=\lambda$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $X_1$ and $X_2$ are Poisson like you describe, and **independent**, then the sum $X_1+X_2$ is indeed Poisson.

The analogue fails for almost all other distributions. But it is true in a few important cases. If $X_1$ and $X_2$ are independent and normally distributed, then $X_1+X_2$ has normal distribution.

If $X_1$ has binomial distribution with parameters $n_1$ and $p$, and $X_2$ has binomial distribution with parameters $n_2$ and $p$, and $X_1$ and $X_2$ are independent, then $X_1+X_2$ has binomial distribution with parameters $n_1+n_2$ and $p$.

But for instance if $X_1$ and $X_2$ are independent with exponential distribution, then $X_1+X_2$ does not have exponential distribution.

If $X_1$ and $X_2$ are independent with uniform distribution, then $X_1+X_2$ does not have uniform distribution.

Comment: Why does it hold for he normal distribution?

Comment: Not helpful reply: because one can prove it, for example by using moment-generating functions, or more awkwardly by an explicit calculation of the convolution.

Comment: @DisplayName If you want to prove it, consider a new variable $Z=X_1+X_2$, and find out the joint probability of $X_1$ taking a value $x_1$ and $X_2$ taking value less than $z-x_2$. This will give you the cdf( cumulative distribution function) of Z.

Comment: Okay thank you, that was what I expected, it is just so, but not necessarily trivial.

Comment: You are welcome. There are good methods for finding thedistribution of the sum of two random variables. In the case of independent Poisson (same parameters or different) they yield that the sum is Poisson. But as mentioned in the answer, one does not have in general "sum of type $T$ random variables has type $T$." As pointed out, it holds in some important cases, but fails in general.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Andre on the fact that it is not necessary for two independent identical random variable's sum to have the same distribution. Regarding your question if it's because $E(X)= Var (x)=\lambda$, I think, it's not the case. Because in case of normal variables, this relation does not hold, yet, it has property that the sum of two normally distributed random variables add up to normal random variable. Hope this helps. Correct me if I'm wrong.